# YouTube Likes using Python & BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, youtube, beautifulsoup

Lots of results for PHP like/dislike results on YouTube but nothing in Python. I want to scrape the number of likes and dislikes using BeautifulSoup as the YouTube-API doesn't include this.

I know the likes and dislikes are contained within this span-class:

```
<span class="watch-likes-dislikes">
<span class="likes">6</span> likes, <span class="dislikes">0</span> dislikes
        </span>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to read the number of likes on a YouTube video by parsing the page with BeautifulSoup, or by using the Google APIs? It would be helpful for people trying to answer your question if you editing your question to eliminate superfluous lines of code, so they could see exactly what you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the HTML looks different now from the ones you provided. Here is how I get the number of likes as of Feb 2017:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import urllib2
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNMlW_5Bmv4"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
soup.find("button",attrs={"title": "I like this"}).get_text()
# as of now, the number of upvote is 3240

# dislike is similar:
soup.find("button",attrs={"title": "I dislike this"}).get_text()
# which is 24 by now
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the [YouTube Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html)?  The video feed contains a

```
<gd:rating average='4.553648' max='5' min='1' numRaters='233' rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall'/>
```

within each `<entry/>`.

Comment: Ok I've looked into it and thats what I want to do but can't figure out how to call the xml file using python and the youtube video_id.

Comment: @David, you can either use the [GData Python client library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/)'s [YouTubeClient.GetVideoEntry](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.youtube.client.html#YouTubeClient-GetVideoEntry) or fetch and parse `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{video_id}` yourself.  Don't forget to register a [developer key](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Developer_Key) if you are making many requests or depending on this service.

Comment: Thank you! http://code.google.com/p/python-youtube-datascraper/source/browse/youtube.py